# Would like to follow javascript link using MechanicalSoup follow_link() or similar

Tags: python-3.x, mechanicalsoup

I would like to follow the link

```
<a href="javascript: GFESubmitForm('credit-report-quotation-report.do')">› Credit Quotation</a>
```

using the `follow_link()` method or similar in the StatefulBrowser package

Using

```
browser.follow_link("javascript: GFESubmitForm('credit-report-quotation-report.do')")
```

causes erros

```
mechanicalsoup.utils.LinkNotFoundError
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since [MechancialSoup doesn't support JavaScript](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#when-to-use-mechanicalsoup), you can either try to manually reconstruct the request if you know what the JavaScript is doing, or use a tool that simulates a fully-fledged browser (and thus includes JavaScript support) such as Selenium.

These options are described in the MechanicalSoup FAQ [here](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails).

Good luck!